# How to extract only email from all the same div tags and same classes with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to extract only eamil but there are same div name and same classes how can I get only email with python scraping?
here is the link from where I want to extract email link: https://www.118100.se/foretag/684047/

```
try:
    email = soup.find_all('div', class_="fc-gray",id=False)

except:
    email = 'No email'
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.118100.se/foretag/684047/'

res = requests.get(link)                 
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
title = soup.select_one("a[href^='mailto:']").get("href").split("mailto:")[1]
print(title)
```

Comment: hi could you please write code to extract all email links from all pages means pagination? here is the main url: https://www.118100.se/sok/foretag/?q=brf&loc=&ob=rel&p=0